# Insert custom Fields to Custom table in DB in checkout page (woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, customization

store data in custom table that i'm created like "mycutom_fileds"

please help me with any reference .

i'm looking to add custom filed in Additional Fields session

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJLJE.png)

*** I want to insert this custom field in custom table in DB

I'm using WooCommerce .

Comment: can you tell us where you want to add a field in the checkout area

Comment: in Additional Fields session

Comment: can you give us screenshots?

Comment: done .. i'm look for any reference

Comment: The hook to be used is `woocommerce_after_order_notes` so [here are all related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=woocommerce_after_order_notes) using this hook. I remember you that we expect you to search before and  to provide in your question your own real code attempt. Related WooCommerce developer documentation: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/).